# Using ISSET with checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, checkbox, isset

I am working on a wordpress search form to refine the current search and what Im trying to do is have the search results page with the search from and it's values set based on the query.

So far I've been successful in doing so with single select drop downs and single checkboxes like so --

```
<!-- SINGLE SELECT -->
    <select name="baths" class="form-control">
    <?php if (isset($_GET['baths'])) {
        $bths = $_GET['baths']; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bths; ?>"><?php echo $bths; ?></option>  
    <?php } else { ?>
    <option value="Any">Any</option>
    <?php } ?>
    <option value="Any">Any</option>
    <option value="1">1+</option>
    <option value="2">2+</option>
    <option value="3">3+</option>
    <option value="4">4+</option>
    <option value="5">5+</option>
    <option value="6">6+</option>
    <option value="7">7+</option>
    <option value="8">8+</option>
    <option value="9">9+</option>
    <option value="10">10+</option>
    </select>

<!-- SINGLE CHECKBOX -->
<input type="checkbox" name="dogs" class="styled" value ="yes" <?php if (isset($_GET['dogs'])) { ?>checked<?php } ?>>
```

That works, but for the multiple values it doesn't. This is my function to generate a set of checkboxes to select amenities -

```
<?php
$amenity_array = array();
$id            = get_query_var('site');
if (!empty($id)) {
  $property_amenities = get_post_meta($id, 'imic_property_amenities', true);
  global $imic_options;
  foreach ($property_amenities as $properties_amenities_temp) {
    if ($properties_amenities_temp != 'Not Selected') {
      array_push($amenity_array, $properties_amenities_temp);
    }
  }
}
global $imic_options;
if (isset($imic_options['properties_amenities']) && count($imic_options['properties_amenities']) > 1) {
  foreach ($imic_options['properties_amenities'] as $properties_amenities) {
    $am_name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $properties_amenities));
    $check   = '';
    if (in_array($properties_amenities, $amenity_array)) {
      $check = 'checked="checked"';
    }

<!-- HERE I TRY TO FIND THE SELECTED CHECKBOXES AND CHECK THEM OFF -->
    if (isset($_GET['p_am'])) {
      $ams = $_GET['p_am'];

      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="p_am" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="p_am" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
    }
<!-- END ISSET -->

  }
} else {
  _e('There is no Properties Amenities', 'framework');
}
?>
```

For the multi select drop down I am using bootstrap multiselect, so on my template the  code looks like this --

```
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2" multiple="multiple">
<?php
 $terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0  ){
   echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
   }
 }
?>
</select>
```

On the page it renders out as ---

```
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2 iOSselect" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
  <option value="Any">All</option>
  <option value="co-op">Co-Op</option>
  <option value="condo">Condo</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default form-control multi-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Property Type" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
  <span class="multiselect-selected-text">Property Type</span> 
  <b class="caret"></b></button>
  <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
      <a tabindex="0" class="multiselect-all">
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">  Select all</label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Any"> All</label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="co-op"> Co-Op</label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="condo"> Condo</label>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Using my code from above my amenities checkbox renders out on the page like so ---

```
<div>
  <label>amenities</label>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_am" class="styled" value="Doorman (Full Time)">
    <label for="doorman(fulltime)">Doorman (Full Time)</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_am" class="styled" value="Doorman (Part Time)"><label for="doorman(parttime)">Doorman (Part Time)</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_am" class="styled" value="Laundry (In-Unit)"><label for="laundry(in-unit)">Laundry (In-Unit)</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_am" class="styled" value="Fitness Center"><label for="fitnesscenter">Fitness Center</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works with my search function allowing users to check off which amenities to include in the query string --

```
p_am=Doorman+%28Full+Time%29&p_am=Indoor+Pool
```

My search function is extensive but as far the relevant parts to the amenities -

```
$amenities = isset($_GET['p_am'])?$_GET['p_am']:'';
$amenities = ($amenities == __('Any', 'framework')) ? '' : $amenities;

// .....

if (!empty($amenities)) {
  array_push($meta_query,array(
    'key' => 'imic_property_amenities',
    'value' => $amenities,
    'compare'=>'LIKE'
  ));
}
```

**UPDATE**

In regards to setting the dropdown options for the bootstrap multiselect, I'm trying to set the options using the following code -

```
<?php 

$taxonomyName = "city-type";

$parent_terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

echo "<select name='property_nhb[]' class='form-control multi-select' id='p-nhb' multiple>";

foreach ( $parent_terms as $pterm ) {
 // echo "<option data-val='" . $pterm->slug . "' value='Any' " . $selected . ">Any</option>";
    //Get the Child terms
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 

if(isset($_GET['property_nhb[]'])) {
$pnhb = $_GET['property_nhb'];

$selected = 'selected';

}

        echo "<option data-val='" . $pterm->slug . "' value='" . $term->slug . "' " . $selected . " >" . $term->name . "</option>"; 
    }
}
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

> My current search function [code](https://pastebin.com/nhHn9xif)

Comment: treat the checkboxes as arrays also and name them.

Comment: what do you mean? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Could you please name your check boxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems a little backwards for creating a search form - it seems more like you're generating a form for each individual result? Annotated code and comments below. I've tried to keep to your coding style in my answer.

```
$amenity_array = array();
$id            = get_query_var('site');
// this first section gets the selected meta properties for the queried property (if available)
// [skipping for brevity ]
global $imic_options;
if (isset($imic_options['properties_amenities']) && count($imic_options['properties_amenities']) > 1) {
  // this loops over all of the globally defined properties
  foreach ($imic_options['properties_amenities'] as $properties_amenities) {
    // gets the name of the property
    $am_name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $properties_amenities));
    // and sets up to check the box if the property has the defined amenity
    // if this is for a search form, why check boxes based on a result?
    $check   = '';
    if (in_array($properties_amenities, $amenity_array)) {
      // note: this only really needs to be 'checked'
      $check = 'checked="checked"';
    }
```

Here's where things go a little cross-purposes, though.

```
    if (isset($_GET['p_am'])) {
      $ams = $_GET['p_am'];

      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="p_am" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="p_am" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
    }
```

This says that all checkboxes have the same name (`"p_am"`) instead of using the loop name for the amenity (`$am_name`) or some form combination if you want all amenities in the same search input array (e.g. `"p_am[$am_name]"`).

Each checkbox would also change the value of `$check` if supplied to the `$_GET` array.

```
      $ams = $_GET['p_am'];
      if (isset($ams[$am_name])) {
        $check = 'checked';
      }
```

Each checkbox would have `name="p_am['.$am_name.']"` as the name.

```
      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="p_am[' . $am_name . ']" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
```

If you want each of the amenities to have unique names (looking at the original checkbox which isn't called `p_am` at all) and not be in an array in PHP, then you would just use the loop name for the amenity (`$am_name`), like so:

```
      if (isset($_GET[$am_name])) {
        $check = 'checked';
      }
```

Each checkbox would have `name="'.$am_name.'"` as the name.

**UPDATE:** after the OP was updated, it looks like every checkbox needs to have the same name, but not be keyed values. For this situation, your checkboxes should be called `p_am[]` (on both search page an original page), and you need to use something like [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) instead of `isset()` to check the result, like so:

```
      if (in_array($properties_amenities, $_GET['p_am'])) {
        $check = 'checked';
      }
```

Additional note - you're also using `$am_name` for the label, without actually setting the `id` attribute on the checkbox to match to, as well as not stripping out non-`id` characters (like parentheses), so the label association won't work.

```
      echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="' . $am_name . '" ' . $check . ' class="styled" value ="' . $properties_amenities . '"><label for="' . $am_name . '">' . $properties_amenities . '</label></div>';
```

For the bootstrap select, you're just missing a check for which options are selected:

```
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2" multiple="multiple">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0  ){
  echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // if the option is 'checked', you need to add the 'selected' atttibute here
    echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
  }
}
?>
</select>
```

So the inside of the loop would look something like this instead:

```
    // for efficiency's sake should live outside the loop as a one-off, but here for illustrative purposes
    $types = $_GET['property_type'];
    $selected = isset($types[$term->slug]) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "'" . $selected . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";
```

If you're using an older version of bootstrap select, you may need to have the selected string be `'selected="selected"` or `data-selected="true"`, depending on the version you're using. For a current version, the above string should be fine.

If the `<select>` isn't meant to be an array of options either (i.e. not multiple), then the `[]` should be removed from the name, and would operate similarly to the checkbox code:

```
<select name="property_type" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0  ){
  echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $type = $_GET['property_type'];
    $selected = isset($type) && $type == $term-slug ? 'selected' : '';
    echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "'" . $selected . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";
  }
}
?>
</select>
```

The original HTML for the `<select>` doesn't actually 'work' as such either - all it's doing is adding a duplicate `<option>` to the top of the options list, and because *nothing* is selected, the form will treat the duplicate created at the top as 'selected' for the `<select>`.

**UPDATE 2:** the reason that the search function is breaking with an array of checkbox inputs is because you are using the `LIKE` comparison for your meta query. From [the documentation on WordPress Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query):

> It can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'.

The documentation also shows examples of how to join these together. Since you haven't supplied how you're actually making the search query this is guessing a little, but it looks like for an array of checkboxes your code should be something similar to:

```
if (!empty($amenities)) {
  foreach ($amenities as $amenity) {
    array_push($meta_query, array(
      'key' => 'imic_property_amenities',
      'value' => $amenity,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ));
  }
}
```

As with the examples in the documentation, you'll need to make sure there's a `relation => 'OR'` or `relation => 'AND'` to define how you want your search to operate.

Comment: I havent checked out your answer in full yet, but to clarify, my search form on the home page works and what I was doing is using the same form on the search results page to refine the search further. So to do so I needed to set the form values to whatever search query was set.

Comment: The first code for the checkboxes works but breaks my search function because of the name change. The second code doesn't do anything though.

Comment: @RichJ you haven't supplied any code in the question for your search function or an example request, so this is basically guesswork.

Comment: @RichJ have updated my answer with for if you're using uniquely named inputs instead of arrays.

Comment: Im not sure if you understand so I updated my question to try and clarify further @leith

Comment: @RichJ updated my answer, although this is making some assumptions about how you're storing your data in WordPress as well. Based on your update, if you have anything working right now with your original setup, it sounds like more of a quirk of WordPress trying to work out what you're doing, rather than correctly parsed information from the form.

Comment: The checkbox code suggestions work but it breaks my search. The select I'm still unsure how to implement the isset. Im going to play around with the code more and update.

Comment: nothing works so far because the checkbox name has to be "p_am" for my search function to work.

Comment: @RichJ I've updated with some notes and a link to documentation on the WordPress Meta Query, hopefully that will be of help. If not, you will need to supply more code on how your search function works.

Comment: I updated my question with my full search function code.

Comment: @RichJ in your latest code in the question, you're still using `[]` in your isset check (won't work), and looks like you've ignored the code advice in both answers about how to indicate which option is selected. Your search function in the paste-bin is also not using the supplied code in my answer - your amenties loop is joining 'IN' `$amenities` instead of 'LIKE' `$amenity`.

Comment: Which code? Cause I tried all the suggestions and havent been able to get it to work.

Comment: @RichJ `$selected` will be undefined (or worse, defined by a previous loop) since you don't supply an `else` block or use a ternary to define it.

Comment: ` if (!empty($amenities)) {
           foreach ($amenities as $amenity) {
              array_push($meta_query,array(
              'relationship'=>'AND',
           array(
              'key' => 'imic_property_amenities',
              'value' => $amenity,
              'compare'=>'LIKE',
           )));
            }
}` like this?

Comment: @RichJ yes, that looks better

Answer (score 2):

<strike>what Fred's meant in the comment is something like this:</strike>

`<input type="checkbox" value="condo" name="var_name[]">`

the `[]` at the end of the name attribute is to tell PHP that it should treat the variable as an array.

and then in the PHP script, you can just check for the array length using somthing like:

`$arr = $_POST['var_name']; echo count($arr);`

based on leith's comment, if it is auto generated, then you should not be bothered to check the checkboxes manually.

instead, just make the selected options be `selected`, for example:

```
<?php
$selections = $_GET['property_type'];   // or something similar
?>
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2" multiple="multiple">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0  ){
    echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $selected = in_array($term->slug, $selections);
        echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "' " . ($selected?' selected':'') . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u1w158tp/

in it you just `selected` the `option`s and it will automatically checked the `checkbox`es

Comment: How does echoing the count help ?

Comment: it does't, it just to show how to get the count of data sent, if it is 0 then do what ever you need to do, you can solve it from there right?

Comment: unfortunately not, my php is still limited. I understand about the brackets for the array, but I'm not sure how to use that with my original code to set the checkboxes/dropdown if needed. @am05mhz

Comment: This isn't correct - the checkboxes you're looking at (for condo, etc.) are auto-generated by bootstrap-select when converting a multi-select `<select>`.

Comment: huh? The checkboxes come from bootstraps multi select, in my template code though all I need to do is set the ID/Class for the select I want to use for multi-select.

Comment: I'm using wordpress with php code to generate my dropdown, however Im having troulble setting the selected options. I've updated my answer with the code. @am05mhz

Comment: Isn't that your checkbox is generated by bootstrap multiselect JS? Why do you still think in PHP?

Comment: It is generated by bootstrap when I add "multiple" to my dropdown. I've tried setting the "selected" options using your code but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: looks like you mixing stuffs up, you have to make a clear separation, which is JS which is PHP, after that, read my answer again, carefully

Comment: I dont get what you mean, how am I mixing js and php ? The js is the multiselect code like in the fiddle, and I've tried your code in the above answer exactly as is.

Comment: I created a new question for the select dropdown only -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012080/isset-with-multi-select-dropdown-and-bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

Your checkboxes has the same name. Try to add different name or use "p_am[]" to treat them as array.