# Isset with multi select dropdown and bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, get, isset

I have a wordpress site with a search form that searches for posts based on the form field selections, for custom fields etc. It works fine, however on the search results page I have an exact copy of the form except that I am trying to preset the form selections based on the search query/url string.

I am using a regular select dropdown and I have set it to "multiple" so that it can use bootstraps multiselect with the checkboxes. I've asked a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557998/using-isset-with-checkboxes) but that was for checkboxes and even though the bootstrap multiselect uses checkboxes, I still have to work with the select dropdown first.

So after trying several things, I've come close but have ran into several problems. In the code below I made notes to further explain exactly what I mean.

```
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2" multiple="multiple">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "property-type", array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
$count = count($terms);

if ( $count > 0  ){
        echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

if (isset($_GET['property_type'])) {
        foreach ($_GET['property_type'] as $proptypes) {

// FIRST EXAMPLE
$selected .= ($proptypes === $term->slug) ? "selected" : "";  // shows first correct selected value but also selects everything after it up until the second correct value, which it doesn't select.
//$selected = ($proptypes === $term->slug) ? "selected" : "";   // shows only last correct selected value
//if ($proptypes === $term->slug) { $selected = 'selected'; }   // shows first correct selected value then selects every value after, even if it wasn't selected

// SECOND EXAMPLE
//$selected .= ($proptypes === $term->slug) ? "selected" : "";  // shows first correct selected value then selects every value after, even if it wasn't selected
//$selected = ($proptypes === $term->slug) ? "selected" : "";   // shows only last correct selected value
//if ($proptypes === $term->slug) { $selected = 'selected'; }   // shows first correct selected value then selects every value after, even if it wasn't selected


    } 
}
      echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "' " . $selected . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";                  // FIRST EXAMPLE

      //echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "' " . ($selected?' selected':'') . ">" . $term->name . "</option>"; // SECOND EXMAPLE 

    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and array and use in_array() to check.

```html
<select name="property_type[]" id="pt-multi" class="form-control multi-select2" multiple="multiple">
<?php
$terms = get_terms("property-type", array('hide_empty' => 0));
$count = count($terms);

// Setup an array of $proptypes
$proptypes = array();
if (isset($_GET['property_type'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['property_type'] as $proptype) {
        $proptypes[] = $proptype;
    }
}

if ($count > 0) {
    echo "<option value='Any'>All</option>";
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $selected = (in_array($term->slug, $proptypes)) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "' " . $selected . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";
    }
}

?>
</select>
```